# Angular 7 select selected attribute option based on passed data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am expiriencing a problem while i am trying to make a select dropdown in angular. 
I want to make one option selected based on the data passed with ngFor. Since I have experienced that I can not use an ngIf and an ngFor at the same time. Even though I do not understand why this is not possible I want to ask the question: "How do I make this work?" The data behind the code is working well. This has been tested. neither can i casually use JQuery to fix it with a `$(document).ready();`

```
<select *ngIf="result.Waarde.length >= 2; else other_content" (change)="onChangeSelected($event.target.value, result)" #select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" *ngIf="result.WaardeStr == waarde.value;" selected>
        {{waarde.value}}
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" *ngIf="result.WaardeStr != waarde.value;">
       {{waarde.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont see what the difference is? you cant apply the `selected` directive to multiple `<option>`'s so the top one becomes irrelevant

Comment: No option is added if the ngIf would return something else then expected. So 1 will be added each tiem. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: the `*ngFor` will effectively "duplicate" whatever it is on, meaning you will have x amount of `<option>`'s all with selected on, if the top condition is met

Comment: the closest thing you could do that should work, is create a filter pipe for the `*ngFor` and filter it instead of using the `*ngIf`

Comment: at this risk of attracting hate, I would like to add to OP that your question and selected answer are in complete mismatch. Your questions asks about attribute `selected` not about the workings and getting the value of selected option.
No offence to submitter of answer: Hardik Patel.

Comment: @PushkaAdhikari you are deffinetly right. The answer is still a fix to get the same outcome as was planned. So i approved it. I did not know this was the correct way of selecting an option within the select element. In my logic i would have to add the select attribute. I was proven wrong by Hardik Patel .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ngModel as below.

```
<select *ngIf="result.Waarde.length >= 2; else other_content" [(ngModel)]="result.WaardeStr" (change)="onChangeSelected($event.target.value, result)" #select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" [value]="waarde.value">
       {{waarde.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This worked! I should research more about why this works though.. Thanks a lot for your help! I am still new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

Place the condition on the `selected` attribute :

```
<select *ngIf="result.Waarde.length >= 2; else other_content" (change)="onChangeSelected($event.target.value, result)" #select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" [attr.selected]="result.WaardeStr == waarde.value">
        {{waarde.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: IMO you can skip the `attr.` part and use `selected`, *nvm the downvote, not by me.*

Comment: Leaving comments that complain about downvoting isn't constructive. It's just noise. No one pays any attention, and there is absolutely no expectation that voters will leave comments.

Comment: This adds selected to all the options.. Only the option that is equal to result.WaardeStr should recieve the attribute selected (not me who downvoted)

Comment: I'm telling you not to leave comments that complain about downvoting or about a lack of comments about downvoting. No one is expected to leave comments to accompany their votes. Votes are anonymous. Comments that try to bully people into revealing how they voted are inappropriate. Comments that just complain about receiving downvotes are pointless noise. Both types of comments will be deleted. I'd rather you save us the trouble of deleting them by not leaving them in the first place. This is not a new site policy. The reason for downvotes appears in the tooltip on the vote arrow, as always.

Comment: @JeroenBerkhof no it would not. `attr.selected` specifically tells to add attribute `selected` if the condition is true. so you may have to modify the condition `result.WaardeStr == waarde.value` but it shouldn't work as you say. Do correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Since i can not upload a picture in the comment section. you probab;y just have to believe me.. I tested the code and that is what happened. Since html shows the last item that has the selected attribute that is what is displayed in the dropdown.

Comment: possibly, I have no reason to not trust you. But question wasn't clear and so weren't the answers. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I should. This was my first question on stack overflow.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select *ngIf="result.Waarde.length >= 2; else other_content" (change)="onChangeSelected($event.target.value, result)" #select class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" [attr.selected]="result.WaardeStr == waarde.value">
    {{waarde.value}}
</option>
```

We have add value attribute then not working selected !!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a comment about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55138258/ (a poorly formatted one), not an answer to the question.

Comment: <select *ngIf="result.Waarde.length >= 2; else other_content" (change)="onChangeSelected($event.target.value, result)" #select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let waarde of result.Waarde" [attr.selected]="result.WaardeStr == waarde.value">
        {{waarde.value}}
    </option>
</select>

Comment: when we have use selected attribute and value attribute not working selected functionality properly